# Locating where two lines of defined length meet, maybe with QGIS Plug-in

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, point

On a site, we recorded various pits by measuring the two distances to two known physical objects (e.g. 20 metres to pit from physical object A, and 10 metres to pit from physical object B).

I am now adding the location of these pits to a polygon layer I'm working on but it is cumbersome measuring 20 metres from object A roughly, then 10 metres from object B roughly, repeating it a few times to get exactly where the two lengths meet up.

Is there a method or a plug-in that would do this easily? (There can be only two possible points where they can meet, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

- Create a circular polygon buffer of width 20m from point feature A.
- Create a second circular polygon buffer of width 10m from point feature B.
- Convert the two polygon buffer features to two line features.
- Intersect the two line features to create two point features at the intersections of the circles. (If you hadn't converted the buffers to line features in the previous step your intersection would be the polygon overlap of two circles instead of two points at the crossing)
- Enable edit on the point features, select the one you know to be correct and delete the other.

Most of the above can be automated by either Python scripts or with a Processing model. My feeling is that if you have less than 10 then do it by hand (much clicking of menus), if you have between 10 and 20 then put in the time to make a Processing model, and if you have more than 20 then (myself) I'd write a script in R but Python could do it just as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation of what @Spacedman suggested in his answer.

In QGIS I can suggest using a `"Virtual Layer"` through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`.

Let's assume we have two point layers `"test"` and `"test2"` with its corresponding attribute tables, see image below.

[image: input]

With the following query, it is possible to create point features at the intersections of the circles representing the distance from objects.

```sql
-- distance from first object, e.g. 50m
WITH Buffer1 AS (
SELECT st_exteriorring(ST_buffer(geometry, 50)) AS geom1
FROM test),

-- distance from second objects, e.g. 40m
Buffer2 AS (
SELECT st_exteriorring(ST_buffer(geometry, 40)) AS geom2
FROM test2)

-- intersection of distances
SELECT st_intersection(geom1, geom2) AS geom
FROM Buffer1, Buffer2
WHERE st_intersects(geom1, geom2)
```

The output Virtual Layer with its Attribute table will look as following

[image: result]

Since [`ST_Dump`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dump.html) is not implemented in QGIS Virtual Layers you will need to apply additionally `'Multipart to singleparts'`. Alternatively, it is possible by means of RECURSION and [`ST_GeometryN`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeometryN.html).